# How do you click on checkbox group in jest?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lwc-jest

I am trying to `JEST` test a `checkbox group` that has `1 option` and when I do `.click()` it says `can't click null property`. Is there a different way I should be hitting it with JEST?

For clarification, the rest of the component does not register as null in JEST, only this checkbox group. I am able to null check everything that would render the checkbox group and it comes back as not null.

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-checkbox-group 
         name="stateCheckbox"
         class="jest-example"
         label="Checkbox Group"
         options={options}
         value={value}
         onchange={handleChange}></lightning-checkbox-group>
```

JavaScript:

```
handleChange(){
     this.isStateCheckboxClicked = !this.isStatementReadClicked;
}
```

**JEST test example:**

```
const stateCheckbox = testedComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('.jest-example');
stateCheckbox.click();
return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
expect(stateCheckbox).not.toBe(null);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that need to add `data-id` to the checkbox group and `querySelector` the `data-id` instead of by class. Then instead of `.click();` you do:

`checkbox.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {label: 'Checkbox Group', value: 'Confirm'}}));`

This allows it to check the box, to then uncheck it you do:

`checkbox.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {label: '', value: ''}}));`